# Heroku postgres maintenance required alert, what to do?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I can see an alert on the heroku postgres console, see attached image.

[image: see the attached image]

It's not clear to me if I have to take some action to enable this maintenance or if this is something heroku will take care of. And it isn't clear neither where to look for help on this topic.

Do I have to worry about something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have received an e-mail with more details (to the address associated with your account). We've added [a FAQ](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/heroku-postgres-january-2014-maintenance-upgrade-faq/349) with some clarifications. If you still have more questions, feel free to reach out to us via [help.heroku.com](https://help.heroku.com/).

Thanks,
Maciek
Heroku Postgres

Comment: Is there a way to configure an alternative email address for maintenance related notifications?